# Python Pyglet тормозит анимация. Медленно отрисовываются объекты на экране

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, opengl

Уже не однократно сталкиваюсь с проблемой торможения анимации при отрисовки различных объектов на Python. Проблема особенно обостряется, когда количество отрисовываемых объектов увеличивается. Я бы не сказал, что объектов прям слишком много: *>= 200 (r=10) окружностей* - уже слайд-шоу.

Я думаю, что дело не в библиотеке, которую я использую ([pyglet](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet)). До этого я использовал [p5py](https://github.com/p5py/p5) аналог p5.js тормоза были ещё сильнее (по правде говоря, создатели p5py знают что она сильно медленнее чем аналоги (Issues с GitHub'a)). Также пробовал Tkinter - думал, что чистый canvas решит мои проблемы. Но этого не произошло. И вот сейчас я запускаю код на Pyglet - получаю слайд-шоу.

Также заметил, что компьютер при тормозящей анимации начинает взлетать на реактивной тяге кулеров. При этом загрузка процессора процессом python'а никогда не превышает 20% (очень странно). Компьютер не совсем калькулятор: *Intel i5-8300H 4 ядра (8 виртуальных) 2.30 GHz*.

**Собственно вопрос, в чем может быть проблема? Анимация 1000 точек не должна превращаться в слайд-шоу, даже если это Python.**

PS. Так же я думаю, что проблема не в моем коде. Точно [такой же](https://github.com/belo4ya/Python-practice/tree/main/some_graphics/Star_field) (не про код ниже) код на p5.js дает плавную анимацию в браузере (но браузер использует видеокарту). Но на всякий случай прикладываю мой последний кол на Pyglet - это не верх оптимизации, но так медленно это работать не должно:

sketch.py

```python
import pyglet
import random
from firework import Firework


window = pyglet.window.Window(400, 400)
main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

fireworks = [Firework(main_batch)]


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main_batch.draw()


def update(dt):
    if random.random() < 0.03:
        fireworks.append(Firework(main_batch))

    for f in fireworks:
        f.update()
        if f.done():
            fireworks.remove(f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1 / 120.0)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

particle.py

```python
import p5
import pyglet


class Particle(pyglet.shapes.Circle):

    def __init__(self, x, y, color, firework, batch=None):
        radius = 2
        if firework:
            radius = 4
        super().__init__(x, y, radius, radius * 5, color, batch)

        self.color = color
        self.firework = firework
        self.opacity = 255
        self._done = False

        self.acc = p5.Vector(0, 0)
        if self.firework:
            self.vel = p5.Vector(0, p5.random_uniform(8, 12))
        else:
            self.vel = p5.Vector.random_2D() * p5.random_uniform(-10, -2)

    @property
    def batch(self):
        return self._batch

    def update(self):
        self.acc += p5.Vector(0, -0.2)

        if not self.firework:
            self.vel *= 0.9
            if self.opacity > 4:
                self.opacity -= 4
            else:
                self._done = True
                self.opacity = 0

        self.vel += self.acc
        pos = p5.Vector(self.x, self.y) + self.vel

        self.x = pos.x
        self.y = pos.y

        self.acc *= 0

    def done(self):
        return self._done
```

firework.py

```python
import p5
import random
from particle import Particle


class Firework:

    def __init__(self, batch):
        self.color = tuple(random.randint(0, 255) for _ in range(3))
        self.firework = Particle(p5.random_uniform(400), 0, self.color, True, batch=batch)
        self.bach = batch
        self._exploded = False
        self.particles = []

    def done(self):
        if self._exploded and len(self.particles) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def explode(self):
        for _ in range(70):
            p = Particle(self.firework.x, self.firework.y, self.color, False, batch=self.firework.batch)
            self.particles.append(p)

    def update(self):
        if not self._exploded:
            self.firework.update()

            if self.firework.vel.y < 0:
                self._exploded = True
                self.explode()
                self.firework.delete()

        for p in self.particles:
            p.update()

            if p.done():
                self.particles.remove(p)
                p.delete()
```

Comment: учитывая, что питон обычно однопоточный, нагрузка в 20% на 8 поточном CPU намекает, что он не справляется

Comment: Значит мне мне не хватает мощности ядра процессора для отрисовки 300 точек - очень странно. А могу я как-то это обойти не меняя структуру программы под multiprocessing и не используя numba.jit. Можно ли просто сказать Python'ону - выполняйся на видеокарте, как браузер? Или это тема для отдельного вопроса?

Comment: Скорее отрисовка 300 кружков. Я не в курсе, как оно там реализовано, но если сделано криво, то действительно, может тормозить. Попробуйте рисовать прямоугольники для начала - там всего два треугольника и оно ну никак не должно тормозить. А лучше сразу учите directx / opengl а питон потом прикрутите, если понадобится.

Comment: Круги рисуются с помощью полигонов (треугольники). Конкретно в этой реализации я использую r * 5 полигонов для каждого круга. Выглядит не идеально, но мне хватает.
А главная проблема в том, что pyglet является оберткой над opengl api. Я думал, хоть оно будет работать быстро и легко, но, как оказалось, нет.

Comment: Ну тогда это действительно печать...

Answer (score 0):

модуль threading

```
import threading
def explode(self):
   ваш_код_который_хотите_сделать_многопотоковым
   
for i in range(5):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=explode, args=(i,))
        my_thread.start()
```